# We need something more than the axioms of ZFC to prove the Dedekind completeness?

Tags: real-analysis, set-theory, foundations

The Dedekind completeness is defined in many ways. Let show one of them to discuss the question.

We define a Dedekind cut $R$ as a non-empty subset of $\Bbb Q$ with this structure:

1. $R$ dont have a minimum
2. If $q\in R$ then $r\in R$ for all $r>q$
3. $\Bbb Q\setminus R\neq\emptyset$

We define $\Bbb R$ as the set of Dedekind cuts. Then we can check that $R\ge R'\iff R\subseteq R'$ define a total order in $\Bbb R$.

Then, from this definition of order, if we have some collection of Dedekind cuts $R_j$ bounded below by $A$ and bounded above by $B$, that is there is a Dedekind cut $A$ such that $R_j\subseteq A$ for all $j$ and a Dedekind cut $B$ such that $B\subseteq R_j$ for all $j$, then we can see that

$$I:=\bigcup_j R_j\quad\text{ and }\quad S:=\bigcap_j R_j$$

defines the infimum and the supremum of the collection of the $R_j$. As @AndreasBleas pointed in the commentaries for the case that $\min(S)=m$ exists, then we take $S\setminus\{m\}$ as the supremum of the collection of $R_j$.

Then my question: I cant see, for this definition, that we need some special axiom as Cauchy sequences or the nested intervals axiom to prove the existence of the infimum and supremum for bounded set of reals.

Then, my question, **we need something more than the axioms of ZFC (by example in this case) to prove that $I$ and $S$ are the infimum or supremum respectively?** The unique thing that we used here is the arbitrary union or intersection of sets, with nothing special in it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, you don't need Cauchy sequences or nested intervals, those are just different ways of construct the set of real numbers

Comment: @Eliana but then there is no need for any special axiom to justify completeness, right?

Comment: Sure, with Dedekind cuts aproach you prove the completeness of the reals, you only need it as an axiom if you are making an axiomatic definition of the real numbers

Comment: When you define the real numbers as "complete ordered field", one of the clauses of the definition (sometimes known as an "axiom") is the completeness.  Is that what you mean by "special axiom to justify completeness"?

Comment: @GEdgar I mean that I read that if you put completeness as a theorem then you need some special axiom to prove it, by example Bolzano-Weiestrass or the nested interval as an axiom. But I dont see here the need for any axiom to show that the arbitrary intersection of Dedekind cuts are the supremum.

Comment: I guess you need to quote what  you read more carefully, or we will not be able to make sense of it.

Comment: @GEdgar [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property#Logical_status) I can read: "in a constructive approach, the property **must be proved as a theorem**, either directly from the construction or as a consequence of some other form of completeness." So, what we need to prove the definition of supremum?

Comment: You don't need to prove the definition of supremum, because it is a definition.  You need an axiom to prove that the supremum is in your set. There are many axioms that guarantee completeness, you choose one as an axiom and prove the rest from it.  The rationals satisfy all the ordered field axioms, so you need a completeness axiom to construct the reals.

Comment: @RossMillikan I will appreciate a lot if you can enlight this question with the axiom that we need here to prove that $S:=\bigcap R_j$ is the supremum, i.e. the least upper bound such that $S\subset R_j$. I cant see what we need here to prove this.

Comment: @Masacroso: As the quote says, one option is to prove it directly from the construction, which is what you have done.  There's nothing more to it than that.

Comment: @EricWofsey then I assume that the supremum, in this case, rely in the uniqueness of intersection of sets, right?

Comment: Your construction of the infimum $I$ is fine, but your $S$ might have a smallest element and might thus fail to be a Dedekind cut because of clause 1 in the definition.  The problem is easy to fix: If $S$ has a smallest element $m$, then $S-\{m\}$ is the supremum that you want.

Comment: @Masacroso: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: @EricWofsey I mean that the unique thing that I think we need to assert that exists some $S$ in the above conditions with $S\subseteq R_j$ such that $S\ge A$ for any other $A\subseteq R_j$ for all $j$ is the uniqueness of $S$, i.e. the intersection operation is a function. In any case the existence of $S$ rely in the operations of sets and it behavior.

Comment: You do need to know some basic facts about sets in order to say that the sets $S$ and $I$ exist, if that's all you're saying.

Comment: @EricWofsey yes, this is what Im saying. Then I realized that for this construction of the reals and all of their properties we only need the axioms of ZFC, nothing more.

Comment: I feel like this question is basically just confusing the notions of theory and model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point here is that "a bounded collection of Dedekind cuts" is just a set of Dedekind cuts. The union of any set is guaranteed by the axiom of union, and since the set is not empty, the intersection of this set is guaranteed to exist by the axiom [schema] of separation.

So indeed, to prove that $\Bbb R$ [exists and that it] is complete we need far less than $\sf ZFC$. We needed extensionality, power set, infinity, union and separation.

This can be pushed even lower by restricting the power set axiom (to say something along the lines "the set of natural numbers has only two power sets", or some other finite number of iterations that is needed here), and to restrict which separation axioms we use. But let's not get ahead of ourselves.