# Dedekind cuts: Why is the union the supremum?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the set $A={\alpha_i}$ of $n$ Dedekind cuts (closed downwards).
The supremum of $A$ is usually defined as the union $\cup_i\alpha_i$.

I find this puzzling/"too much effort". Is it not the case that this union is in fact the *largest* $\alpha_i$, where order is defined in terms of set inclusion? If it is right, I'm just wondering why the supremum of $A$ is not usually defined simply as the *largest* $\alpha_i$?

Comment: Probably you are seeing the standard way to define Dedekind cuts, what is a bit clunky and not as easy to follow as other ways to define Dedekind cuts. Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974963/we-need-something-more-than-the-axioms-of-zfc-to-prove-the-dedekind-completeness) question where Dedekind cuts are defined in a more simple way than the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the set over which you take the supremum doesn't need to have a single largest element.

Consider for example the Dedekind cuts
$$M_n = \{r \in \mathbb{Q} \mid r < -\tfrac{1}{n}\}$$
for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. The supremum of these cuts is given by the cut $\{r \in \mathbb{Q} \mid r < 0\}$, which is not of the form $M_n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!