# The supremum axiom for real numbers.

Tags: calculus, order-theory, real-numbers

¡Hi!

I have a question respect this axiom...

Usually in courses of calculus beggin with the  real numbers satisfy the field axioms and they satisfy some order properties. After that they say the real numbers satisfy this axiom. But my question is, if can i start using Dedekind cuts, can i prove this axiom with Dedikind cuts? Or independent of how i starts, is this an axiom?

Comment: from Dedekind cuts it is a theorem, not an axiom. Take also a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974963/we-need-something-more-than-the-axioms-of-zfc-to-prove-the-dedekind-completeness)

Comment: ...so yes, you can prove it using Dedekind cuts.

Comment: It's not that you're proving the axiom *with* Dedekind cuts, so much as you are *defining* the real numbers *to be* the Dedekind cuts of the rational numbers (the rational number need their own definition beforehand). If you define the real numbers in this way, then the supremum axiom is a theorem.

Comment: think about that: the Dedekind cuts are used to construct the real numbers, so they must have all the properties of real numbers.